# Installing self hosted chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, registry

We have created a chrome extension for our Team Members and we want to self host it.

I am aware of the non-web store install policies and I feel like I have set this up correctly but it does not work.

Here is what I have:

I set up my manifest with an update url and an extension id key like this:

```
{
  "update_url": "https://ourownserver.com/extensions/updates.xml",
  "key":"obljkonioibfihfjbaiidbobmckpkned",
 ....
}
```

I created `updates.xml` like this:

```
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="2.0">
    <app appid="obljkonioibfihfjbaiidbobmckpkned">
        <updatecheck codebase="some-extension.crx" version="3.6"/>
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

I used the `chrome://extensions` to package the .crx and .pem files and droped them all into `https://ourownserver.com/extensions/` like this:

[image: ;]

I used regedit to add the [`ExtensionInstallWhitelist`](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallWhitelist) and [`ExtensionInstallSources`](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources) under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` as follows:

[image]

[image]

I then closed Chrome and re-opened it

After doing all of this, I expect that going to `https://ourownserver.com/extensions/extensionName.crx` will instal the extension and that it will be enabled. However, if I go `https://ourownserver.com/extensions/extensionName.crx` I still get:

[image]

And on the extensions tab, it is installed but disabled and has this message:

[image]

Im thinking that I have not added the registry entries correctly but I cant find a more detailed walkthrough to be sure.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: In your updates.xml have you tried putting the full path to you extension in codebase="bookit-feedback.crx". I.e. https://ourownserver.com/extensions/bookit-feedback.crx (or where ever it's hosted.) rather than just bookit-feedback.crx?

Comment: @dan75 Thanks, that did it. I wouldnt have thought that would matter for the initial install but indeed, using an absolute path in `updates.xml` fixed the issue. If you throw up an answer, I'll accept it :), thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad it worked.

Comment: One quest DelightedDDD, did the computers have to set up a Active Directory Domain? I ask because we have an extension that we want host ourselves but we're not a Windows company so have no AD servers or Windows domains.

Comment: @h00ligan No ADs, youll need to set ExtensionInstallWhitelist and ExtensionInstallSources  (linked in the question) differently depending on your OS but that yeah, whats listed above is all we had to do with the notable correction of using an absolute path in the xml file

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'll give this a try then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update XML needs to contain the absolute path of the extension CRX, rather than the relative one. For example:

```
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="2.0">
    <app appid="obljkonioibfihfjbaiidbobmckpkned">
        <updatecheck codebase="https://ourownserver.com/extensions/some-extension.crx" version="3.6"/>
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

Comment: Something else I discovered today, the "*referrer* must be in the ExtensionInstallSources list. What I mean is that you cannot simply put `https://ourownserver.com/extensions/some-extension.crx` in the address bar and have it install the extension. You must put a link somewhere on `https://ourownserver.com` pointing to `https://ourownserver.com/extensions/some-extension.crx` and have users actually click that link so that the request **comes from https://ourownserver.com**. Pulled my hair out for an hour last night over that littel detail